# sending data from website to localhost php file

Tags: php, curl

I am sending data from website to localhost using curl php.
But it shows me results

```
bool(false)
```

**my function is**

```
public function postCURL($postData){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://192.168.1.27/abc/index.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
        }
```

My link is `http://192.168.1.27/abc/index.php`

Comment: Enableing error logging in apache/php should give what you are doing wrong I guess.

Comment: How Enable error logging in Online Server???

Comment: Ah, it's not your own server? If so, you sure 192.168.1.27 is reachable from that server? Because that's a RFC1918 (internal network) address

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that @MarkvanHerpen.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a local IP address from outside your local network, you will get an `unable to connect` error.

Also, you have `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = 0` which tells `curl_exec($ch);` not to return anything. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` [as per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

[curl_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) translates any non boolean response (null in your case I would think) as `false`.

Comment: Another problem too then. `if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch); }` will tell us what the error is ...

Comment: You should use that code right after the `curl_exec` line, if there's an error it will display `Error: This is your error.`

Comment: This is error now showing `Error: couldn't connect to host`

Comment: I thing keep in my that i am sending request from live webiste and `http://192.168.1.27/abc/index.php` this link is my internal localhost page link @Egg

Comment: Is your local host on the same network?! A live website hosted by a company will not be able to connect to `http://192.168.1.27` ... that is a local IP.

Comment: yes .. this is local ip .. is that possible what i am trying to do?>?

Comment: No. Being very simplistic, your web server has no idea who/where a `192.168.*.*` is.

Comment: @Egg any solution to this issue?

Comment: @MUzair are you able to solve it? if yes then would you please explain